# How to refine a mixed type to something that has `toString()`?

Tags: types, flowtype

Well in flow for error reporting I often take "mixed data" and "log to console the data". This data hence has to support `toString()` - but doesn't any type in javascript support `toString()`?

So in flow, how would I tell flow not to choke over things like:

```
printError(data: mixed) {
    console.log(`Data is: ${data}`);
}
```

or:

```
printError(data: mixed) {
    console.log(`Data is: {data.toString()}`);
}
```

Without having to refine the type manually.

Comment: `undefined`, `null`, and objects without a prototype chain (e.g., `Object.create(null)`) do not have a `toString` method. However, these values would be included in the `mixed` type.

Comment: How would i then define something that "can but put into a template string"?

Comment: Would `JSON.stringify` work in your case (`console.log('Data is: ' + JSON.stringify(data))`)? It will print objects more gracefully and handle `any` data so that you don't need to worry about types.